# Spring Inheritance Autowired Annotations

Tags: spring

For inheritance I see examples using XML Definition. I had a doubt using Autowire and Annotations.

I have

```
@Component
class A{

}

@Component
class B extends A{

}

class TestClass{
    @Autowire
    A aObj;
}
```

So I believe this will inject Object of Class A. Correct ?
Also If I make my class A as abstract, it will inject Class B object. Correct ?

Also it would be good if someone can give me a link to example for this.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see by yourself?

Comment: I am trying. But I think I am missing something in my dependency. I am getting errors. So I thought meanwhile if someone can give me good explanation it would be much helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the code and got the results as follows.

For above it throws NoUniqueBeanException.

2. If I make Class A as abstract it injects Class B Bean and works fine.
3. If I don't want to make class A as abstract I need to Use Qualifiers as follows

   ```
   @Component(value="aBean")
   class A{

   }

   @Component(value="bBean")
   class B extends A{

   }

   class TestClass{
       @Autowire
       @Qualifier(value="aBean")
       A aObj;
   }
   ```

   This injects Class A bean.